# More than one constraint for scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy

I am trying to perform a constrained nonlinear optimization problem, specifically minimization problem, using `scipy.optimize.minimize`. Specifically, I am trying to perform the `constrained linear regression`, which can be written as:

**Min y-(b<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub>+b<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub>+...+b<sub>n</sub>x<sub>n</sub>+b<sub>n+1</sub>x<sub>n+1</sub>+....b<sub>p</sub>x<sub>p</sub>)**

**subject to**
**b<sub>1</sub>+b<sub>2</sub>+...+b<sub>n</sub> = 1,**

**b<sub>n+1</sub>+b<sub>n+2</sub>+...+b<sub>p</sub> = 1,**

**0 <= b<sub>i</sub> <= 1 for i=1,2,...,p**

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import warnings

def loss(x):
    loss_function = np.sum(np.square((np.dot(x, m) - y)))
    return loss_function

m = np.vstack([var_1, var_2, var_3,..., var_n, var_n+1,...,var_p])
y = np.array(ret['var_y'])

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0})

x0 = np.zeros(m.shape[0])

res = minimize(loss, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons,
                   bounds=[(0, 1) for i in range(m.shape[0])], options={'disp': True})
```

My question is, how do I implement those constraints into this model?

Comment: You're trying to add *nonlinear* constraints to a constrained *linear* regression?

Comment: @Joel hmm.. I am not sure. but that's the problem I am solving. Are my constraints nonlinear? The objective function is definitely linear, but I am not sure.

Comment: You said in the first sentence that you wanted to perform a constrained nonlinear optimization problem, but you're using `constrained linear regression`

Comment: @Joel An optimization problem is nonlinear if either objective function or constraint is nonlinear, right? So I guess I am using `constrained nonlinear regression`